# C# code How to write method for number between 0 to 20

Tags: c#

How to add method here to find out the number must be between 0 and 20?
And I want to Use TryParse() method to check that an integer has been entered is  between 0 to 20 and that should be but here if i enter 21 that is also working which is wrong please help! here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int number;
    int a = 0;
    char ec;
    Write("Enter number of participants between 0 to 20 >> ");
    while (a == 0)
    {

        if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out number))
        {
            a = 1;
            WriteLine("the expected revenue is " + ComputeRevenue(number).ToString("C"));
            Sport[] player = new Sport[number];

            for (int x = 0; x < number; x++)
            {
                player[x] = new Sport();
                Write("Enter Player Name #{0} >> ", x + 1);
               
                player[x].EventCode = ReadLine()[0];

            }
```

Comment: `if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out number) && number is >= 0 and <= 20)`

Comment: Ask yourself, where do you check that the entered number is in this range?

Answer (score 1):

You  are not checking the value of the number you read.
You can check it with a simple if condition.

```
int number;
        int a = 0;
        char ec;
        Write("Enter number of participants between 0 to 20 >> ");
        while (a == 0)
        {
            
               if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out number))
               {
                if(number>=0 && number<20){
                   a = 1;
                   WriteLine("the expected revenue is " + ComputeRevenue(number).ToString("C"));
                   Sport[] player = new Sport[number];

                   for (int x = 0; x < number; x++)
                   {
                       player[x] = new Sport();
                       Write("Enter Player Name #{0} >> ", x + 1);
                   
                       player[x].EventCode = ReadLine()[0];

                   }
                }
```